# Is there an alternative way of saying something has been 'a topic of dispute"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, history, politics

I want to write about the extent to which Malcolm X brought about any change to the Civil Rights Movement through his civil rights activism and that this has been '**a topic of dispute**' among revisionist historians.

Is there an alternative way of phrasing this that sounds better? I don't want to use the words debate or discussed either as they are too weak in my opinion.

Comment: ***bone of contention***

Comment: **fought out** or **fought over**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a ***controversial issue or a [controversy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Controversial+issue)*** :

> dispute, argument, or debate, esp one concerning a matter about which there is strong disagreement and esp one carried on in public or in the press.

(Collins Dictionary)